# The right way to build a dynamic personal website for a physics student?

Tags: web, portfolio

Trying to figure out how to build and deploy a dynamic personal / professional website.

The original vision is:

### Pages

- Main page - should contain basic **about me** information. A few
  paragraphs, photos and social media links. At the bottom, there could
  be an email subscribe form. The header will present the main subpage
  links for navigation.
- Blog page - contains posts (articles). These are displayed in chronological order of publication, from newest to oldest. They could also be modified. Date and time of the latest modification is displayed on the blog page and the page of the article itself.
  People can comment on those articles. There's no registration for users.
- Contact me page - incoming users can type in the email and text message into a contact form. These messages would be sent in form of emails to my email inbox. I've almost setup Gmail SMTP server for this
- Portfolio page - would display my published works, projects, and it'll also include the CV / Resume.

### A few thoughts

The website would need to be dynamic in order to store articles and comment. The website would also showcase content in different languages depending on the IP location of the user, unless the user himself explicitly chose a particular language to be displayed on the website. That info would be store in cookies.

It would also need to have its own CMS to manage these efficiently / easily.

With an option to subscribe to the email list, every time a blog article is published, a new email notification will be sent to the subscribers.

I am asking, because I don't know where to start. There are so many ways and choices, that it's hard to wrap your head around this.

### Also key things to consider

- Not sure what database to use. Though I have some familiarity with SQL like ones
- Backend framework. This is a project that doesn't need any complicated stuff. Basics are good enough. Not sure what could be used here. Node / Express looks interesting though
- Hosting. Ideally would want to get a free tier hosting, but I am not excluding paid options under 10 $. I think I still have the GitHub Student Developer Pack tools available.
- Analytics. Google Analytics seems to be ok, but if there's a way to gather analytics and making it even faster for the user, that would be preferable.
- WebAssembly. Is that a thing? I've heard it can speed up the front end JavaScript, but only if the code is large enough.
- CDN. Does it come as an extra cost? Or is it built in, for the most hosting platforms?
- Cloud platforms. Or maybe it just makes more sense to somehow deploy it on the cloud? I think Azure is included in GitHub Student Developer Pack.

Anything to suggest?